# @NativeQuery ORA-00942: table or view does not exist - SpringBoot

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, nativequery

so I'm trying to do a native query to fetch some data from an Oracle Database and I keep getting this error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not
> exist

My Query is this one:

```
@Query(
        value = "select d.* from DEFAULT_GROUP d " +
            "inner join COMPANIA_DEFAULT_GROUP cd on d.ID = cd.DEFAULT_GROUP_ID " +
            "inner join COMPANIA c on c.ID = cd.COMPANIA_ID " +
            "where c.ID = cast(:companiaId AS NUMBER) and lower(d.NAME) like lower(cast(:dgName AS varchar(255))) ORDER BY d.NAME ASC " ,
        nativeQuery = true
    )
    List<DefaultGroup> findDefaultGroupsByNameLike(@Param("companiaId") Long companiaId,@Param("dgName") String dgName);
```

My entity **Compania** is like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Compania")
@Table(
    name = "compania"
)
public class Compania {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "compania_sequence",
        sequenceName = "compania_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,
        generator = "compania_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
        nullable = false
    )
    private Long id;


    @Column(
        name = "name",
        nullable = false,
        unique = true
    )
    private String name;

    @Column(
        name = "dominio"
    )
    private String dominio;

    @Column(
        name = "altas"
    )
    private String altas;

    @Column(
        name = "bajas"
    )
    private String bajas;

    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<DefaultGroup> default_group;

    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<Office> office;

    public Compania() {
    }

    public Compania(String name, String dominio, String altas, String bajas, List<DefaultGroup> defaultGroup, List<Office> office) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dominio = dominio;
        this.altas = altas;
        this.bajas = bajas;
        this.default_group = defaultGroup;
        this.office = office;
    }
    ... Getters and Setters...
```

And my entity **Default Group** is like this:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class DefaultGroup {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name = "defaultGroup_sequence",
        sequenceName = "defaultGroup_sequence",
        allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
        strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator = "defaultGroup_sequence"
    )
    @Column(
        nullable = false
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(
        name = "name",
        nullable = false
    )
    private String name;

    @Column(
        name = "path",
        nullable = false
    )
    private String path;

    public DefaultGroup() {
    }

    public DefaultGroup(String name, String path) {
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
    }
   ... Getters and Setters...
```

When I check the failures in the Azure Insights I see that it is trying this SQL:

> /* dynamic native SQL query */ select d.* from DEFAULT_GROUP d inner
> join COMPANIA_DEFAULT_GROUP cd on d.ID = cd.DEFAULT_GROUP_ID inner
> join COMPANIA c on c.ID = cd.COMPANIA_ID where c.ID = cast(? AS
> NUMBER) and lower(d.NAME) like lower(cast(? AS varchar(?))) ORDER BY
> d.NAME ASC

Then throws me a *500 internal server error* and the oracle error code *ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*

I've also seen this error at the end of the errorstack:

```
Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 141, Sql = /* dynamic native SQL query */ select d.* from DEFAULT_GROUP d inner join COMPANIA_DEFAULT_GROUP cd on d.ID = cd.DEFAULT_GROUP_ID inner join COMPANIA c on c.ID = cd.COMPANIA_ID where c.ID = cast(:1  AS NUMBER) and lower(d.NAME) like lower(cast(:2  AS varchar(255))) ORDER BY d.NAME ASC , OriginalSql = /* dynamic native SQL query */ select d.* from DEFAULT_GROUP d inner join COMPANIA_DEFAULT_GROUP cd on d.ID = cd.DEFAULT_GROUP_ID inner join COMPANIA c on c.ID = cd.COMPANIA_ID where c.ID = cast(? AS NUMBER) and lower(d.NAME) like lower(cast(? AS varchar(255))) ORDER BY d.NAME ASC , Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The same thing happens with my other table that is called OFFICE

The tables that the database has are:

- COMPANIA
- COMPANIA_DEFAULT_GROUP (ids of both entities)
- COMPANIA_OFFICE (ids of both entities)
- DEFAULT_GROUP
- OFFICE

Answer (score 1):

I suspect some kind of case sensitive table naming issue here.  To be safe, please explicitly set the table `name` using the `@Entity` annotation:

```java
@Entity(name = "COMPANIA")
public class Compania {
    ...
}

@Entity(name = "DEFAULT_GROUP")
public class DefaultGroup {
    ...
}

@Entity(name = "COMPANIA_DEFAULT_GROUP")
public class CompanyDefaultGroup {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Should I also change column names and table name?

Comment: AFAIK `@Table` is redundant here, as the `name` inside `@Entity` already will be propagated to the underlying table.  Not sure on column names, but that isn't the source of your current error message.

Comment: Ok thank, ill try this and I'll  keep you updated! Thanks!

Comment: It's still throwing me the same error, Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 141, I think that points to COMPANIA, but I don't know what is wrong there :S